# webpack css loader svg and png

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have the next webpack config.

```
 plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin()

    ],
    module: {
     rules: [
         {
             test: /\.css$/,
             use: [
                 'style-loader',
                 'css-loader'
             ]

         }
         ],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
```

After build the webpack I get an error:
***You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.*** in svg string whicnh get from css file. How can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Add `url-loader` or `file-loader` to handle those extensions.

```
        {
            test: /.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg)$/,
            use: ['file-loader'],
        },
```

(excerpt from https://github.com/akx/demystifying-webpack/blob/162137118dd54f30a6c98dd0ae8844dba733483e/webpack.config.js#L13-L16)